# Spark - No FileSystem for scheme: https, cannot load files from Amazon S3

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to load some data from an Amazon S3 bucket by:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Importer");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx.sc());

DataFrame magento = sqlContext.read().json("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/*/*.json");
```

This last line however throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https
```

The same line has been working in another project, what am I missing? I'm running Spark on a Hortonworks CentOS VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spark supports HDFS, S3 and local.
S3 can be accessed by s3a:// or s3n:// protocols ([difference between s3a, s3n and s3 protocols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356041/technically-what-is-the-difference-between-s3n-s3a-and-s3)

So to access a file the best is to use the following:

```
s3a://bucket-name/key
```

Depending on your spark version and included libraries you may need to add external jars:

[Spark read file from S3 using sc.textFile ("s3n://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851244/spark-read-file-from-s3-using-sc-textfile-s3n)

(Are you sure that you were using s3 with https protocol in previous projects? Maybe you had custom code or jars included to support https protocol?)