# How to load RDDs from S3 files from spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a text file in S3 that I would like to load into an RDD with `spark-shell`.

I have downloaded [Spark 2.3.0 for Hadoop](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). Naively, I would expect that I just need to set the hadoop settings and I'd be set.

```
val inFile = "s3a://some/path"
val accessKey = "some-access-key"
val secretKey = "some-secret-key"

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)

sc.textFile(inFile).count()

println(run())
```

Invoking the final line returns:

```
Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found)
```

This seems to be asking that I provide the library which includes S3AFileSystem. No problem - I download the appropriate jar and add this line to the beginning of the script.

```
:require C:\{path-to-jar}\hadoop-aws-3.1.0.jar
```

Now, running the script fails at the final line with a variety of errors similar to this:

```
error: error while loading Partition, class file 'C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar(org/apache/spark/Partition.class)' has location not matching its contents: contains class Partition
```

I'm lost at this point - clearly, it had no issue defining the `run` method before.

I can access the Partition class myself directly, but something is happening above that prevents the code from accessing Partition.

```
scala> new org.apache.spark.Partition {def index = 3}
res6: org.apache.spark.Partition = $anon$1@3
```

Curiously, running the final line of the script yields a different error in subsequent invocations.

```
scala> sc.textFile(inFile).count()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  ...
```

The [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream.html) claims this is part of hadoop 3.1.0, which I'm using, but when exploring `hadoop-aws-3.1.0.jar` I see no trace of `StreamCapabilities`.

Is there a different jar I should be using? Am I trying to solve this problem incorrectly? Or, have I fallen into the XY problem trap?

## Answers I tried

- [The official docs](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html) assume I'm running the script on a cluster. But I'm running `spark-shell` locally.
- [This other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851244/spark-read-file-from-s3-using-sc-textfile-s3n) is for an older problem. I'm using s3a as a result, but am encountering a different problem.
- I also tried using every jar of Hadoop from 2.6 to 3.1, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities` is in hadoop-common-3.1.jar
You are probably mixing version of Hadoop JARs, which, as coved in the [s3a troubleshooting docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#Classpath_Setup) is doomed.

Spark shell works fine with the right JARs in. But ASF Spark releases don't work with Hadoop 3.x yet, due to some outstanding issues. Stick to Hadoop 2.8.x and you'll get good S3 performance without so much pain.

Comment: Hello Steve, I've been using a mix of spark 2.4 and hadoop 3 without issue so far is there known incompatibility ?

Answer (score 0):

I found **a** path that fixed the issue, *but I have no idea why*.

1. Create an SBT IntelliJ project
2. Include the below dependencies and overrides
3. Run the script (sans `require` statement) from `sbt console`

   ```
   scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.1.0"
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.1.0"

   dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
   dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
   dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7"
   ```

The key part, naturally, is overriding the jackson dependencies.